# Making text relative to background svg in HTML5

Tags: css, html, svg

I have the following HTML code that renders a number on top of a red svg frame circle which is again on top of an icon/image.Currently the text in svg is '8' which renders fine.But, if I change the test to a two digit number, the position changes. How can I make it's position relative to the svg frame? You can try the HTML here :

```css
    .icon {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .txt {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 15px;
    }
    .text {
      background: ;
      font-size: xx-small;
      position: absolute;
      top: 6px;
      left: 19px;
      color: white
    }
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img src="http://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/win10-logo.jpg" alt="none" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <svg class="txt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" fill="red" />
  </svg>
  <div class="text">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rearranged things a bit, but this seems to do the trick. Even works with triple-digits. Bit cramped, but it works.

http://codepen.io/Fortyseven/pen/ZGwOvR

```
<style>
    .icon { 
        background:      url("http://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/win10-logo.jpg");
        background-size: 30px 30px;
        width:           30px; 
        height:          30px;
    }
    .badge { 
        position:      relative;
        top:           5px;
        left:          15px;
    }
    .badge svg, 
    .badge .text {
        width:  15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
    .badge .text { 
        font-size:  xx-small;
        color:      white;
        position:   absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top:        1px;
        left:       -1px;
    }
</style>
<div class="icon">
    <div class="badge">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" fill="red" /></svg>
        <div class="text">99</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I improved on this a bit. Now it's all CSS, no SVG. Badge expands to fit the amount of text. [http://codepen.io/Fortyseven/pen/PqLZLR](http://codepen.io/Fortyseven/pen/PqLZLR?editors=110)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the svg [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) element and set its [`text-anchor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) attribute to `middle` so it is centered.

```css
.icon {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      position: relative;
    }
.txt {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img src="http://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/win10-logo.jpg" alt="none" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <svg class="txt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="6.5" fill="red" />
    <text x="6.5" y="9.7" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#FFF" font-size="10">13</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, nice! I need to get more familiar with the SVG stuff. I didn't realize it had such [widespread support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg).